# Replacing a set of values in a column multiple times with a set of values in another column

Tags: r

```
mydata = data.frame(year=rep(2000:2010,10), values1=rep(letters[1:5],22))
mydata1 = data.frame(year=c(2005:2009),values2=letters[5:9])
```

I want to substitute all the `mydata$values1` in my data for the `mydata$year` (2005:2009) with the values in `mydata1$values2`. This has to be done multiple times as (2005:2009) occurs repeatedly in `mydata$year`. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a join `on` 'year' and assign (`:=`) the values

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydata)[mydata1, values1 := values2, on = .(year)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with base R

```
mydata = data.frame(year=rep(2000:2010,10), values1=rep(letters[1:5],22), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
mydata1 = data.frame(year=c(2005:2009),values2=letters[10:14], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

m <- merge(mydata, mydata1, all.x=TRUE)
m$values1 <- ifelse(is.na(m$values2), m$values1, m$values2)
```

For the last line one can write:

```
i <- !is.na(m$values2)
m$values1[i] <- m$values2[i]
```

Comment: I could not think of this even though I have worked with merge. Good technique. Thanks

Comment: The final line could also be written `m$values1[!is.na(m$values2)] <- m$values2[!is.na(m$values2)]` though I'm not sure this is probably less readable.